# How to save a dictionary of datetime indices?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I get this error when I try to use JSON:

```
TypeError: <class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2012-02-19 02:30:00, ..., 2012-03-19 04:43:00]
Length: 47910, Freq: None, Timezone: None is not JSON serializable
```

The dictionary is in the format {str: datetimeindex, str: datetimeindex...}

Comment: You need to specify what you mean by "save" - dump to json?

Answer (score 0):

You can zip them together after calling the `to_native_types` method eg.

```
d = dict(zip('abcd', [pd.date_range('2014-01-01', periods=3).to_native_types() for i in range(4)]))
print(json.dumps(d))
```

yields

```
{"a": ["2014-01-01", "2014-01-02", "2014-01-03"], "b": ["2014-01-01", "2014-01-02", "2014-01-03"], "c": ["2014-01-01", "2014-01-02", "2014-01-03"], "d": ["2014-01-01", "2014-01-02", "2014-01-03"]}
```